# Sub menu of sub menu is not inline

Tags: html, css, menu

I m new to HTML and try to create menu in HTML using css. I created a 2 level css drop down menu but the problem is that the sub menu of sub menu or 2nd level menu is not displaying in line as it should.

here is HTML file:

```
<nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="menuList"><a href="#" class="menuItem">Menu 1</a></li>

            <li class="menuList">
                <a href="#" class="menuItem">Menu 2</a>
                <ul class="menuLevel1">

                    <li class="subMenu1">
                        <a href="#" class="itemLevel1">Sub menu 1</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="subMenu1">
                        <a href="#" class="itemLevel1">Sub menu 2</a>
                        <ul class="menuLevel2">
                            <li class="subMenu2"><a href="#" class="itemLevel2">Sub Sub menu 1</a></li>
                            <li class="subMenu2"><a href="#" class="itemLevel2">Sub Sub menu 2</a></li>
                            <li class="subMenu2"><a href="#" class="itemLevel2">Sub Sub menu 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="subMenu1">
                        <a href="#" class="itemLevel1">Sub menu 3</a>
                        <ul class="menuLevel2">
                            <li class="subMenu2"><a href="#" class="itemLevel2">Sub Sub menu 1</a></li>
                            <li class="subMenu2"><a href="#" class="itemLevel2">Sub Sub menu 2</a></li>
                            <li class="subMenu2"><a href="#" class="itemLevel2">Sub Sub menu 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menuList"><a href="#" class="menuItem">Menu 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

And css file:

```
.menuBar {
background-color: #92CCDA;
}
ul{
float: left;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
}
.menuList{
float: left;
}
.menuItem{
display: block;
width: 100px;
height: 25px;
padding: 10px;
background-color: #92CCDA;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
}
a:hover {
background-color: orange;
}
.menuLevel1{
display: none;
}
.subMenu1 {
display: block;
}
.itemLevel1{
display: block;
width: 120px;
height: 25px;
background-color: #92CCDA;
text-align: center;
padding: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
}
li:hover ul.menuLevel1 {
display: block;
position: absolute;
}
.menuLevel2 {
display: none;
}
.itemLevel2{
display: block;
width: 120px;
height: 25px;
background-color: #92CCDA;
text-align: center;
padding: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
}
.menuLevel1 li:hover ul.menuLevel2{
display:block;
position: absolute;
left:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Just do the following:

- add `position:relative;` to `.subMenu1` to make it act as a reference for the position absolute of its children.
- set `top: 0` on the absolute positioned `.menuLevel2` to make it's top line up with the top of it's parent.

That should fix it. Check the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hcKHy/1/